# Select and drag multiple rows in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

Thanks in advance.

I have a requirement of selecting multiple rows in a table using checkbox and drag all the selected rows at once to another div.
The scenario is same as Gmail

Is there any external library or simple JavaScript approach to achieve this in react?

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for a similar feature. I have built my own component for this with the help of antd table.

hope this will help for some other users who are searching for the same

https://github.com/sojinantony01/react-multi-row-dragable-table-antd